# ¿Como serializar un array en JQuery con el mismo esquema de PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, array

forma de serializar un array en PHP

```
$value = array(array('Nombre','Adam'),array('Nombre','Exael'));
echo serialize($value);
/*a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Nombre";i:1;s:4:"Adam";}i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Nombre";i:1;s:5:"Exael";}} */
```

Ahora necesito serializar lo mismo pero en Jquery

```
var values = [['Nombre','Adam'],['Nombre','Exael']];
?
```

Comment: Serializarlo para que? para deserializarlo en PHP? o para almacenarlo en algun medio local (ej. localStorage).. Te lo pregunto para entender el caso de uso y poder proponerte una solucion apropiada.

Comment: @md tiene razón, porque probablemente te convenga usar *JSON* tanto en PHP como JS.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo correcto, aparentemente hizo la pregunta y se fue. cuando aparezca sabremos :P

Comment: @md lo que quiero es serializar un array hecho en Jquery, he buscado y la mayoria me lo serializa de la siguiente manera: nombre='adam'&nombre='exael', y lo que necesito es que me saque el mismo formato que sale al serializar en php, no se si me explico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pude hacer una función personalizada en javascript que serialize el arreglo de la misma forma que lo hace `serilaize` y que pueda deserializarse con `unserilize`, pero no tiene mucho sentido por que tanto Javascript como php comparten una API que sirve para intercambiar datos estructurados (Arrays, Objetos o una combinación de estos) llamada JSON.

JSON es el acronimo de Javascript Object Notation y actualmente es la técnica mas usada de transferencia de datos en todas las plataformas, incluyendo Javascript, PHP, Java, C#, Ptyhon, etc. por que es simple, tiene un overhead relativamente bajo (comparado con XML o HTML por ejemplo) y todas las plataformas lo soportan.

Entonces, en Javascript serializas con, [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjh2NHc2vTPAhXIG5AKHR9mARoQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fstringify&usg=AFQjCNHRzqPt6xnPVFwpf_Y2BtQyyTZpIw&bvm=bv.136593572,d.Y2I):

```js
var estructura = [["a","b"],{ "c": "d"}];

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(estructura)
)
```

Lo deserializas con [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjdk-vn2vTPAhWMHJAKHdQjAfYQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON%2Fparse&usg=AFQjCNHkowMNeO8CgweprUJz3xDY9HxuPQ&bvm=bv.136593572,d.Y2I).

```js
var json = '[["a","b"],{ "c": "d"}]';

console.log(
  JSON.parse(json)
)
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, los resultados son prácticamente idénticos, pero esto pasa  por que `JSON` es nativo de javascript.

En PHP tienes las funciones, [`json_decode`](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjFkfqA2_TPAhWDhZAKHXmIAtQQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.json-decode.php&usg=AFQjCNEfzaIfzofmQZOFSYuv9P5S_iMCJA&bvm=bv.136593572,d.Y2I) para deserializar y [`json_encode`](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2_-Hy2vTPAhVEkJAKHWIkASAQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.json-encode.php&usg=AFQjCNFwbWEXtXdU7euW3Qpv8NQ8zkaLMw&bvm=bv.136593572,d.Y2I) para serializar.

```
$value = json_decode('[["Nombre","Adam"],["Nombre","Exael"]]');
echo serialize($value);
/*a:2:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Nombre";i:1;s:4:"Adam";}i:1;a:2:{i:0;s:6:"Nombre";i:1;s:5:"Exael";}} */


$value2 = array(array('Nombre','Adam'),array('Nombre','Exael'));
var $json = json_encode($value2);
/*[["Nombre","Adam"],["Nombre","Exael"]]*/
```

Basicamente, estos metodos te permiten intercambiar estructuras complejas de datos entre javascript, php y muchas otras tecnolgias.

Por ultimo, si estas enterado de que es una REST API o también una REST Full API, estas APIs se basan en la gran mayoría de los casos en el formato JSON, por las razones que te explique arriba.

No te preocupes que no mencione JQuery, pues se basa en javascript y es compatible y de hecho utiliza la [JSON API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) del navegador.

Salu2